# Basic PHP inheritance

Tags: php, oop

I'm brand new to OOP and I have a question that's gotta be pretty damn basic, but I'm having trouble explaining it in a concise way so it's hard to search for answers.

I have an application that supports credit card processing and I want to abstract the processing capabilities so I can add other providers (linkpoint, authorize.net, etc).  I think what I want to do is create a simple class that looks something like this:

```
class credit {

    function __construct($provider){
        // load the credit payment class of $provider
    }

}
```

Then I'll have the providers each extend this class, eg

```
class linkpoint extends credit { }
```

But I really want to use the credit class more like an interface, sort of.  I don't want a credit object, I want to do something like:

```
$credit = new credit('linkpoint');
```

Then I want $credit to be an instance of the linkpoint class.  Or at least, I want all the methods to execute the code defined in the linkpoint class.

What's the best way to approach that?  Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called "[**factory pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)" (see also [Design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern))

You can handle it like this

```
class Credit
{
  public function __construct($factory)
  {
    $object = null;

    switch($factory) {
      case 'linkpoint':
        $object = new linkpoint();
        break;
      case 'xy':
        //...
    }
    return $object;
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it! Thank you!  Note: Brian below mentioned it should be done with a method within the Credit class.  Is that best practice instead of using the constructor?

Comment: Well it helps to follow back the code, but if you name it `CreditFactory` or something like this then it speaks for itself. But at the end it comes to a matter of taste and of consistency in your whole project. I would probably stick to dependency injection which is mentioned also, because this is more coupled and has no magic creation of objects. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I'm getting this right, but when you want to $credit being an instance of linkpoint then you just have to do

```
$linkPointCredit = new linkpoint();
```

Btw. Your class names should always start with a capital letter.

**Update:**

Then you can indeed use a factory pattern.

```
class Credit
{
    private $provider;

    public function __construct($provider)
    {
        if(class_exists($provider) {
            $this->provider = new $provider();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it should not be named `$credit`, it should be named `$linkpointcredit` or something more specific.

Comment: I want to be able to create it more programatically though.  If I'm loading the parameter of which provider to use from a database for example, I want to just throw it at the $credit class as I've described above.  All the methods will be the same for each class (ie each will have a charge, refund, etc. method).  so once it's instantiated the app itself is agnostic to the credit provider.

Comment: Thanks Johannes - I gave the answer to Dan because he mentioned the factory pattern first.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described sounds like a [Factory Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  Except instead of using the constructor, you would have a class (static) method on your base `Credit` class which returns an instance of one of your subclasses, depending on the string that was passed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend "Dependancy Injection".

```
class credit {

    function __construct(Provider $provider)
    {
        $this->setProvider($provider);
    }

}

class Provider {}
class Linkpoint extends Provider {}
class crossave extends Provider {}
class Debitcentral extends Provider {}
```

Then you can use them like:

```
$linkpoint = new Linkpoint();
$credit = new Credit($linkpoint);

$crossave = new Crossave();
$credit = new Credit($crossave);

$debitcentral = new Debitcentral();
$credit = new Credit($debitcentral);
// etc...
```